# Invalid SSID name using vt6656 and WEXT under linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

Hardware: Technexion TDM3730 module on custom baseboard. 
Software: linux kernel v.2.6.37 based on Technexion's distribution

Initially, I have 2 variations of TDM3730 module: with and without wifi chip.
Module that contains WiFi chip onboard, uses libertas_sdio driver and nl80211 and works fine.
But I want to attach external WiFi module to another module variation.

I have usb WiFi module VT6656, and my linux kernel already have corresponding driver (in stage subdirectory). Driver insmod runs fine, registering eth1 interface. 
"ifconfig eth1 some.my.ip.addr up" runs OK, but I have two strange messages:
"Config_FileOperation file Not exist" and "Zone=[2][E][U]"
Then "iwlist eth1 scan" runs OK, I can see all of our wifi nets.
So i'm making wpa_passphrase and getting config:

network={
    ssid="Intelligent Soldering Room"
    #psk="my_psk_in_text"
    psk=my_psk_in_hex_string
}

And finally when I'm calling
wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -ieth1 -c /path/to/my/conf
I'm getting message from vt6656 driver like
Scanning [g¦isQ Jü)=¦ëªvóF|TT°Z.c3ßãÚ] not found, disconnected !

Looks like name that not contained any non-ASCII characters, was passed to driver incorrectly (same config for on-board wifi chips works totally fine). But what is the reason of such name corruption? wpa_supplicant aplication, WEXT driver, vt6656 driver? Is there known way to fix the problem?

Comment: What happens without spaces in the name? See example 4: http://webconverger.org/wireless/

Comment: Without spaces - same effect. I guess, there is encoding mismatch is hiding somewhere.